# Unity Crashes On LoadAll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I try to execute the following line of code, my unity3d Crashes without further nothice.

```
allmeshes = Resources.LoadAll("Meshes",typeof(Mesh)) as Mesh[];
```

Could it be because it wants to Load too much data at once or is it something different?

Comment: Might very well be. Did you check the log?

Comment: didn't say much unfortunately

Comment: @Emscape Have you tested a smaller set of resources or using `Resources.Load` to load each mesh separately to see if/when the problem occurs?

Comment: Yes that was the solution thx Jerdak. The resources were corrupted (still don't know why that happened) but managed to reload them into the project.